# Delete element in a list that do not meet certain conditions using a loop

Tags: python, list, pycharm

While reading a list 'lst', I want to remove an delement that does not meet certain condition. Based on the following answer: [Strange result when removing item from a list while iterating over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-it) I found a solution that works great. Here is the code in PyCharm:

```
for ind, el in enumerate(lst):
    if not el.strip() or el.strip() != 'LABEL':
        lst[ind] = None #  here I get a warning concerning ind
    else:
        break
lst = [n for n in lst if n is not None]
```

I cannot figure out why I receive this warning:

```
Unexpected type(s): (int, None) Possible type(s): (SupportsIndex, str) (slice, Iterable[str]) 
Inspection info:
Reports type errors in function call expressions, targets, and return values. In a dynamically typed language, this is possible in a limited number of cases.
Types of function parameters can be specified in docstrings or in Python 3 function annotations.
```

Comment: Also, the `not el.strip()` part seems redundant, and why do you `break` after the first valid element? And why not do it all in a list comp in the first place?

Comment: @tobias_k I believe they want to keep the first `"LABEL"` and everything that follows it.

Comment: @tobias_k right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't see the rest of the code but you probably type-hinted your `lst` to have `str` elements only and `None` is not a `str`.

You don't have to implement a 2-pass algorithm to remove elements though. The following should be equivalent to your code, sans warnings (see [docs for `dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile)):

```
from itertools import dropwhile

lst = list(dropwhile(lambda el: el.strip() != 'LABEL', lst))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use list comprehension and do it all on one line. See the code below:

```py
new_list = [x for x in lst if x.strip() != 'LABEL']
```

One more thing, I don't it is a good idea to modify a list while looping through it.

Comment: This won't produce the same output as the OPs code (note the `break` statement in the original). Also, `I don't it is a good idea to modify a list while looping through it`: Why not? That's exactly what `list`s are for. That's why they are mutable while many other data structures in Python are not.

Comment: With modifying a list while looping through it you can read the answer that was given to the question the OP included in his question. Here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/6260097/11979729

Comment: @DanielAfriyie Note the difference between "modifying" and "adding/deleting elements". Just editing or even replacing elements while you loop the list is usually fine.

Comment: @tobias_k Ok. I got it.